# Migration already Exist but no table created

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5.4

So I have been migrating `create_password_resets_table` but then again it doesn't reflect on phpMyAdmin. The connection has been established but I **can't see the table** that I migrated. How can I fix this? I tried resetting and rollback but it says there's nothing to rollback.

```
php artisan make:migration create_password_resets_table --table=password_resets


[InvalidArgumentException]
A CreatePasswordResetsTable migration already exists.
```

Comment: rollback your migration, correct it and run again

Comment: It says there's nothing to rollback.

Comment: Did you do `php artisan migrate` ?

Comment: Yes sir. I did it.

Comment: Command that you posted just creates migration-file. Then you have to edit it for your purpose and run

Comment: Try removing CreatePasswordResetsTable entry in migration table and check

Comment: There's already a schema or table information inside the file. How do I run it? Thank you Sir. 

  Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });

Comment: Where did you get error message? When you're execute those command?

Comment: There's no error message sir. There's just no table created after the migration.

Comment: So where did you get A CreatePasswordResetsTable migration already exists?

Comment: When I run php artisan migrate it says:php artisan migrate 

 the table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Comment: So I check the status of my migration: 
| Ran? | Migration                                      |
| N    | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table           |
| N    | 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table |
| N    | 2017_04_04_094855_createtableposts             |

Comment: Could you look in your migration table? there must be the entry for your `create_password_resets_table`. Remove and re-run the migrations and you will be in the track.

Comment: I think you have several migrations with one table name or several migrations with same name

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: @CarloC.Aquino this issue is due to class name 'CreatePasswordResetsTable'  already exists please try with different name or check all the files inside database/migrations directory and remove already exists class file.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop table migrations and after that run `php artisan migrate`, or you can run `php artisan migrate:refresh`.